# Why break cannot be used in ternary operator in python?

Tags: python, break

I am a curious little bit, why the break statement is not working in ternary operator in Python?
Ternary operator here I am referring to this syntax `[on_true] if [expression] else [on_false]`

Below is my code

```
import random

def rolldice():
    print(random.randint(1, 6))

while True:
    ip = input("Roll dice ? y/n ")

    # Below line will gives you SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    # rolldice() if ip == 'y' or ip =='Y' else break

    if ip == 'y' or ip =='Y':
        rolldice()
    else:
        break
```

The commented line `rolldice() if ip == 'y' or ip =='Y' else break` is not working while another code syntax which is logically similar to this one is working fine.

Comment: The ternary operator is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: This is probably related to the same reason that "if" can be used without the "else", but "A if X else B" will not work without the else.